# Using more than one IP in DNS Cloudflare?

Tags: server, cloudflare

I have a question: What happens if I put 2 IPs on a specific path to a domain in the DNS of Clafflare

Example :

type :  A
name : www
ip : ip1

type :  A
name : www
ip : ip2

INFO: The two servers contain the same content, files and everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to do is called "[Round-robin DNS](https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/how-to/round-robin-dns/)", this setup will work and allow you to split traffic between two servers.

From Cloudflare documentation:

> To randomly distribute traffic across multiple servers, set up multiple DNS A or AAAA records for the same hostname.

> Use this setup for simple, [round-robin load balancing](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/glossary/round-robin-dns/). If you need more fine-grained control over traffic distribution — including automatic failover, intelligent routing, and more — set up [our add-on load balancing service](https://developers.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/).